# Codedeploy fails with BundleType must be either YAML or JSON

Tags: aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I followed the codepipeline wizard to create a Codebuild and Codedeploy project.

My codebuild script produces a single artifact, an `appspec.yml` file that's supposed to get passed to codedeploy.

I've tested the file manually via the Codedeploy GUI and the deployment works, however every time I run the pipeline Codedeploy fails with the error `BundleType must be either YAML or JSON`

The appspec.yml file;

```
version: 0.0 
Resources:
  - hello-world:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
        Name: "hello-world"
        Alias: "staging"
        CurrentVersion: "5"
        TargetVersion: "22"
```

My `buildspec.yml`

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - ./build.sh
artifacts:
  files:
    - appspec.yaml
  discard-paths: yes
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your appspec is `appspec.yml` but you specify `appspec.yaml` in your `buildspec.yml` - note the `yml` versus `yaml`. Update your `buildspec.yml` with the right extension, and your issue should be solved.